# R - Position of an element of a list that contains a sequence of characters

Tags: r, list, indexing

I experimenting with getting data from a pdf file. 
I have a table lost in the middle of a page. So far I have managed to create a list of characters, e.g. `print(list_April)`

```
[1] "                 Agricultural exportation                                          SEPTEMBER 2019"              
 [2] "        á  Prior Month                 â  Prior Month"              
 [3] "                                       production                     Prices                    Current Account"             
 [4] "       April"                                                                                                       
 [5] "          Survey                       % increase                       % increase                         US$bn"              
 [6] "                                2018      2019       2020      2018       2019      2020           2018        2019        2020"    
 [7] "   Belgium                        1.4       1.1         1.1       2.1        1.6       1.6           -7.0        -4.0        -3.0"  
 [8] "   Canada                         1.9       1.5        1.7       2.3        2.0       2.0         -45.1        -34.8       -32.3"   
 [9] "   France                         1.7       1.3         1.2       1.9        1.2       1.3        -18.3        -16.7       -17.3"   
[10] "   Germany                        1.5       0.5        1.0      1.8        1.4      1.5        289.3       272.8       271.5"       
[11] "   Italy                          0.9       0.0         0.4       1.2        0.8       1.1          52.0         50.0        48.3"  
[12] "   Japan                          0.8       1.0        0.2      1.0        0.6      0.8         175.4       173.2       180.9"      
[13] "   Netherlands                    2.6       1.7        1.4      1.7        2.5       1.6          99.4         86.7        87.9"    
[14] "   Norway                         2.2       2.3        1.8       2.7        2.3      1.8          35.0         29.0        30.4"    
[15] "   Spain                          2.6       2.2        1.8       1.7        0.9       1.2          13.1          8.7         8.1"   
[16] "   Sweden                         2.4       1.6         1.4      2.0        1.8       1.8           9.6        19.2        18.6"    
[17] "   Switzerland                    2.8       1.0        1.3      0.9        0.5      0.7         72.2         70.2        68.5"      
[18] "   United Kingdom                 1.4       1.2         1.1      2.4        2.0      2.1       -109.1      -116.9      -106.6"      
[19] "   United States                  2.9       2.3         1.8      2.4        1.8       2.1        -491.0      -528.5      -562.2"    
[20] "   North America1                 2.8       2.2         1.8       2.4        1.8       2.1        -536.1      -563.3      -594.5"   
[21] "   Western Europe2                1.8       1.1         1.2       1.8        1.4       1.5         495.2       454.4       456.9"   
[22] "   European Union2                2.0       1.3         1.3       1.8        1.5       1.6         378.5       341.5       340.2"   
[23] "   Euro zone2                     1.9       1.1         1.1      1.8        1.3       1.3        396.7       383.3       374.0"     
[24] "   Asia Pacific3                  4.7       4.3         4.1       2.0        2.0       2.1         349.1       404.0       357.0"   
[25] "   Eastern Europe4,7              3.2       1.8         2.6       6.1        6.1       5.4          68.0         57.4        36.0"  
[26] "   LatAm ex Venezuela5 ,7         1.4       0.9         2.0       9.5        9.6       7.7        -102.3        -87.8       -95.3"  
[27] "   Other Countries6               2.6       2.4         2.8       6.7        4.9       5.4          66.4         28.3        16.5"  
[28] "  Total7                          3.2       2.6         2.5       2.9        2.6       2.6"
```

I want to be able to get the position where the element contain a specific sequence of characters. e.g. `function(list_april, "Belgium")` that would return `7`

I have played a bit with `match` or `str_locate`, but have not reached a satsifying result yet.

Comment: Did you try `grep('Belgium', list_april)`?

Comment: Indeed it works perfectly. As it is just that I have not been able to find the right function, should I delete my question ?

Comment: I'm rather new to this stackoverflow shindig myself, so I can't advise either way!